# How to successfully push files from IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I am new to git and github so bear with me.

I have a Java project, I shared the project on GitHub following steps in this video more or less: [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf2-MOl0VXY&list=WL&index=7&t=0s)

Then I deleted directory I had project in on my local hard drive. Then I cloned repository from GitHub and imported project into IDEA.

Now I want to:

- add projectname-master.iml that was ignored in previous version
- update .gitignore so it no longer ignores projectname-master.iml

I committed only those two files into default changelog.
I added remote to project with VCS->Git->Remotes->paste link to repo->OK

And then I tried VCS->Git->Push and here I selected:

- master->origin:master
- my commit is selected

When I click `Push` I get error: `Push to origin/master was rejected`

How can I fix this and make updating files easy? By the way repository is private, does this have any impact?

Comment: `projectname-master.iml` is Intellij IEAD specific file and should not be pushed to repositories like git. If you really what to do that and you want to be familiar with git, I encourage you to use a terminal or git-bash if you are on windows, and use commands like `git status` and `git push` to understand what's going on: reallythe output of these commands helps a lot :)

Comment: It is totally fine to push IDEA project files to any repository. It all depends on what one wants to achieve. Having project configuration in git will help other users if they also use IntelliJ. And BTW, output of all git commands IDE executes is available in the IDE without a need to go to the terminal.

Comment: @A.Henteti Just so you know, iml file contains information about what folders are source and what aren't. My FXML in resources folder won't load if iml file doesn't specify it as source root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out importing project from cloned zip is not a good idea.

From IDEA start menu -> Check out from Version Control -> Git -> Clone project. This will automatically associate the remote.

Comment: In fact, downloading a zip with sources from GitHub is not a clone? as no git is involved in the procedure. If you need an association with git, you need to clone using git, or Get from VCS action in the Intellij

Answer (score 0):

Check the Console tab of the Version Control toolwindow to see details on why the push was rejected.

The most common reason for the rejected push is "non-fast-forward" error - which means there are commits on the remote repository that are missing in your clone and have to be pulled first.

But since you added a remote manually, the push might be rejected due to "refusing to merge unrelated histories" error - which would mean there are no common commits in your current repository and the remote repository. This will happen if you specified a different repository as a remote, not the one you pushed to initially.

Actually cloning creates the origin remote, so not sure why you needed to add it manually.